Unable to Draw Custom Border Around SWT Group Encompassing Title Area on Linux
In an SWT Java application, I am trying to draw a custom black border around the Group widget (with title text) that encompasses the entire group, including the title area. The goal was to ensure the border surrounds the group and includes the title space without obstructing the title text. However, the custom border is not drawn correctly around the entire group on Linux(RHEL 8). On windows it is working.

Actual behavior:



Expected behavior:



System Information:

Eclipse Version: 2019-09 R (4.13)
SWT Version: 4928
OS: Linux (RHEL 8)
Java Version: 11

Implemented a function drawBorderOnGroup to draw a border around the SWT Group, ensuring it encompassed the title area. This included using a PaintListener and Event.gc.drawRectangle() to attempt to draw the border correctly.
public static void drawBorderOnGroup(Group group){
    group.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            @Override
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                e.gc.setForeground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
                Rectangle clientArea = group.getClientArea();

                e.gc.drawRectangle(0, 0, clientArea.width - 1, clientArea.height - 1);
            }
        });
}


How Group is implemented varies quite a bit between platforms. On some platforms a Composite containing separate controls for the title and text is used and the client area is only the text - making it difficult to do what you want on all platforms.

yea, after some research found out that, Linux has reserved some space for title and does not allows(not sure but i wan not able to) draw over it. Is creating a custom group using composite class that behaves as group is my final option? or there are another ways? @greg-449

If you want this to look the same on all platforms a Composite is probably the best solution.
